# Adding Python 2.7 to registry

Tags: python, python-2.7

The python installer does not create a python folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software.

I've tried using this: http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm script but it returns an error: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

What can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the original problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: i am trying to install pywin32-220 but it can't find python in the registry.

Comment: How did you install python?

Comment: Maybe you just need to add it to your PATH variable ?

Comment: Installed it via original python installer from python.org for all users.

Comment: Why don't you do this manually? Open regedit, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE and add key. The rest of the information is in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, for some reason even though python is still not in the registry the pywin32-220 installer now recognized the python 2.7 installation path.I have not changed anything just tried the installer several times.